# How to create an array from the lines of a command's output

Tags: arrays, bash, text-parsing

I have a file called `failedfiles.txt` with the following content:

```
failed1
failed2
failed3
```

I need to use grep to return the content on each line in that file, and save the output in a list to be accessed. So I want something like this:

```
temp_list=$(grep "[a-z]" failedfiles.txt)
```

However, the problem with this is that when I type

```
echo ${temp_list[0]}
```

I get the following output:

```
failed1 failed2 failed3
```

But what I want is when I do:

```
echo ${temp_list[0]}
```

to print

```
failed1
```

and when I do:

```
echo ${temp_list[1]}
```

to print

```
failed2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need to add the lines to an array? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did *not* create an array.  What you did was [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) which would simply put the output of a command into a *variable*.

In order to create an array, say:

```
temp_list=( $(grep "[a-z]" failedfiles.txt) )
```

You might also want to refer to [Guide on Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

Comment: doesn't grep return a list of the lines where a match of the pattern was found?

Comment: So my argument ( well really im just trying to understand guru ) didn't I assign the return type to temp_list?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Could you elaborate what you're attempting to clarify?

Comment: @kolonel I'm not sure what you mean by _return type_.  However, what you did simply caused the output of the program to be assigned to a variable called `temp_list`.  It did not create the array.  If you quote the variable while printing, you might figure it: `echo "$temp_list"`

Comment: Guru what terms should I search for so I can read about the expansion that is occurring here.

Comment: @kolonel Added a couple of links that might help.

Answer (score 12):

@devnull's helpful answer explains why your code didn't work as expected: command substitution always returns a *single string* (possibly composed of multiple lines).

However, **simply putting `(...)` around a command substitution to create an array of *lines* will only work as expected if the lines output by the command do not have embedded spaces** - otherwise, each individual (whitespace-separated) word will become its own array element.

---

#### Capturing command output lines at once, in an *array*:

To capture the lines output by an arbitrary command in an *array*, use the following:

- **bash < 4** (e.g., on OSX as of OS X 10.9.2): use `read -a`

```sh
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a linesArray <<<"$(grep "[a-z]" failedfiles.txt)"
```

- **bash >= 4**: use `readarray`:

```sh
readarray -t linesArray <<<"$(grep "[a-z]" failedfiles.txt)"
```

Note:

- `<<<` initiates a so-called [*here-string*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString), which pipes the string to its right (which happens to be the result of a command substitution here) into the command on the left via `stdin`.

  - While `command <<< string` is functionally equivalent to `echo string | command` in principle, the crucial difference is that the latter creates *subshells*, which make variable assignments in `command` pointless - they are localized to each subshell.
- An alternative to combining here-strings with command substitution is [input] [*process substitution*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) - `<(...)` - which, simply put, allows using a command's output as if it were an input file; the equivalent of `<<<"$(command)"` is `< <(command)`.
- `read`: `-a` reads into an array, and `IFS=$'\n'` ensures that every line is considered a separate field and thus read into its own array element; `-d ''` ensures that ALL lines are read at once (before breaking them into fields); `-r` turns interpretation of escape sequence in the input off.
- `readarray` (also callable as `mapfile`) directly breaks input lines into an array of lines; `-t` ensures that the terminating `\n` is NOT included in the array elements.

---

#### *Looping* over command output lines:

If there is no need to capture all lines in an *array at once* and *looping* over a command's output line by line is sufficient, use the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # ...
done < <(grep "[a-z]" failedfiles.txt)
```

- `IFS=` ensures that each line is read unmodified in terms of whitespace; remove it to have leading and trailing whitespace trimmed.
- `-r` ensures that the lines are read 'raw' in that substrings in the input that look like escape sequences - e.g., `\t` - are NOT interpreted as such.
- Note the use of [input] process substitution (explained above) to provide the command output as input to the `read` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The proper and portable way to loop over lines in a file is simply

```
while read -r line; do
    ... something with "$line"
done <failedfiles.txt
```