# BASH entry of multiple numeric values by user

Tags: string, bash, python-3.x, int

I am working on a script for taking multiple ip addresses from the user. I am not sure if I can use BASH or Python to allow the user to input all values in one paste action. The current process is:

```
echo -e "Enter prefixes separated by spaces with  CIDR):"
read PREFIXES
#Declaring the array for number of prefixes entered

declare -a prefix_entered=($PREFIXES)
```

But this causes the user to have to enter each group of ip addresses in one long string. Is there a better way? Thanks

Sorry for the confusion. So in stead of making the user paste a string like this:

```
191.248.25.0/16 191.252.24.0/24 191.252.128.0/24 191.252.64.0/24 191.252.16.128/25 191.252.32.128/25 191.252.25.64/26
```

[image: row of ips instead of line]

I want them to be able to enter it like this:

```
191.248.25.0/16
191.252.24.0/24
191.252.128.0/24
191.252.64.0/24
191.252.16.128/25
191.252.32.128/25
191.252.25.64/26
```

But it throws an error. I understand because it needs to be made into an array but I am not sure how.
Thanks

Hopefully this image will help in making my question more understandable.

Comment: "to allow the user to input all values in one paste action" and "But this causes the user to have to enter each group of ip addresses in one long string" are contradictory, no? How do you want the pasted input to look like? Please add an example.

Comment: learning how to comment on this site. I have edited the original post. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Example added, :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since IPs cannot contain stars, spaces, or other funny characters, you can use an unquoted variable and split on IFS. Example:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
ip=$(cat)    # type the ips you want, seperated by space, tab, 
             # or newline, When done, press Ctrl-D
# Note that $ip is intentionally left unquoted
prefix_entered=($ip)
printf "%s\n" "${prefix_entered[@]}"

$ ./script.sh 
 191.248.25.0/16 191.252.24.0/24 191.252.128.0/24 191.252.64.0/24 191.252.16.128/25 191.252.32.128/25 191.252.25.64/26 # <-- Pressed enter and ctrl-D here
191.248.25.0/16
191.252.24.0/24
191.252.128.0/24
191.252.64.0/24
191.252.16.128/25
191.252.32.128/25
191.252.25.64/26

$ ./script.sh 
191.252.24.0/24
191.252.128.0/24
191.252.64.0/24
191.252.16.128/25
191.252.32.128/25
191.252.25.64/26     # <-- Pressed enter and ctrl-D here
191.252.24.0/24
191.252.128.0/24
191.252.64.0/24
191.252.16.128/25
191.252.32.128/25
191.252.25.64/26
```

Comment: I will try it and post back if it works for what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Okay, so what I was trying to ask was, I want the ips to be entered in in rows NOT in a line. But I do appreciate this. This is like what I am currently working with.

Comment: @akrhodey: This should work both with rows and line by line.

Comment: Okay, you did do it the way I was looking for. It just took me a second to figure how to impliment it for my setup. Thank you, this really works for my setup.

Comment: @akrhodey: I made an edit to make it a bit briefer, in case you are interested...

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner for bash versions >=4 thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776917/2877364):

```
readarray -t prefix_entered
```

That will accept the list from the user and store it in the array `prefix_entered`, one element per line.  The user still has to hit Control-D at the end of the list to tell `readarray` that there are no more addresses.